# Braintree + Wordpress: How do I associate new users with a BT customer ID?

Tags: php, wordpress, braintree, payment-processing

I am new to web development. I decided to start by using WordPress.
I am reading through the BT API and I'm at the section to use the `Customer` object to create, update, find, and delete a customer/payment info.

But I don't understand the correlation between WordPress and integrating payment processing yet. In WordPress, users create a login specifically for my site, right?

Would I need to hack WP to allow them to also associate a Braintree customer ID with that login? I don't understand the relationship between WordPress and integrating payment processing....

Comment: You *could* do an integration yourself, but you probably want to search for an e-commerce plugin.

Answer (score 0):

@doublesharp's comment is right. It's possible to build your own Braintree plugin in Wordpress, but there are lots of options that exist to help you do this.

I don't want to endorse any specific product, but some searching online would yield a few options for you. This is really the best route to go if you are new to web development.

[Wordpress can be awesome](http://www.awwwards.com/websites/wordpress/) for a lot of cases, but you have [to understand a fair bit about it](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/08/how-to-become-a-top-wordpress-developer/) before you build plugins that are of high quality.

Comment: Oh totally, I agree. But when I looked, there was no product that fit my needs. I need the payment processing company to be Braintree and I need to be able to process the payment of one user and send it to another. That was way more complex than what I found. However, would you recommend me modifying the Braintree plugin I found?

Comment: I really wish I could help, but that question is a really complex one. That would be akin to asking "I have found a painter to make me some wall art, what should I ask him to paint?" Every single WP plugin is different and every process is different. My ultra high-level (see:orbital) advice would be to figure out what experience you are getting with the current plugin and then plot what experience you want to get and make small changes to get there. I would recommend trying to find a Wordpress/PHP mentor in your area to help you learn more if you don't want to go the consultant route.

Comment: I hear ya. +1 for the orbital bit.